# Efficient method of checking if a string starts with one of a set of strings

Tags: python

I have a need to match a string to see if it starts with one of about 40 strings, and this method gets called a heck of a lot.

Currently it does

```
for pref, newval in list_of_prefixes:
    if oldval.startswith(pref):
         return newval
return oldval
```

However, given it's called a huge number of times,  it makes sense for this to be efficient as possible. I could ensure list_of_prefixes is sorted, and then drop out of the loop as soon as pref > oldval, but that doesn't seem to gain a great deal.

Currently the largest number of input values fall somewhere between two of the prefixes, so I could explicitly test for that, or search in reverse order, but although this is efficient for the data set now, it might be less efficient should the data set change.

Originally, there was only 1 possible prefix, so performance was perhaps less of an issue.

I looked at string.startswith(tuple()) but that seems only to make it easier to write, and it doesn't tell me which tuple matched, so where there is a match I have to do the check twice.

Comment: Sounds like a case for regex, for once.

Comment: Do the prefixes have predictable length?  You could put your list of prefixes into a dictionary and then look up oldval[:x] for all x where x is a possible length of a prefix. Especially as the list of prefixes grows, the dictionary lookup will be faster.

Comment: @jgfoot You are basically reinventing regular expressions, except the state machine in a regex is a network where each node can have multiple outgoing paths associated with a set of acceptable characters; this also removes the requirement for the strings to be of a fixed length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a compiled regular expression, I would expect the overhead of compiling a regex to pay itself back when you have more than just a few strings.  Basically, the compiled regex is an automaton which runs out of traversable paths pretty quickly if the prefix is not one which the automaton recognizes.  Especially if all the matches are anchored to the beginning of the string, it should fail very quickly when there is no match.

```
import re

prefixes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
rx = re.compile(''.join(['^(?:', '|'.join(prefixes), ')']))
for line in input:
    match = rx.match(line)
    if match:
        matched = match.group(0)
```

If you need a more complex regular expression (say, one with trailing context after the closing parenthesis), you will want to use regular grouping parentheses `(` instead of non-grouping `(?:`, and fetch `group(1)` instead.

Here is the same with a dictionary mapping prefixes to replacements:

```
prefixes = {'foo': 'nu', 'bar': 'beer', 'baz': 'base'}
rx = re.compile(''.join(['^(?:', '|'.join(prefixes.keys()), ')']))
for line in input:
    match = rx.match(line)
    if match:
        newval = prefixes[match.group(0)]
```

Actually, as pointed out in comments, the `^` is not strictly necessary with [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match).

Comment: You don't need to define the variable `match`.  You can do `if rx.match(line):`.

Comment: @zondo I assume the OP wants to know which prefix matched, not just whether a prefix matched.

Comment: Do you need a ^ for re.match?

Comment: @TomTanner Actually, you don't; thanks for pointing this out. Old habit.

Comment: I looked at the perf: with 100 prefixes and more than a million lines, OP's code takes 20s, yours 1.7s. (I wanted to post a similar answer but benchmark it first :p )

Comment: @viod: Thanks!  I just updated to use `(?:` which might improve performance ever so slightly.  If you still have your test rig, maybe you want to retest with this change also. Anyway, real-world performance will depend heavily on what the prefixes are, how many there are, and what the input looks like.

Comment: @tripleee: no significant change, still 1.7s! prefixes and inputs have all been generated from base64-ed /dev/urandom, so probably not real-life-like :p